# Tabulator Date Edito min max value

Tags: javascript, tabulator

There is a Tabulator(js) library.
In the "editorParams" section, how to replace the MAX value with the value from the adjacent row cell (date format)?

```
{title:"Example", field:"example", editor:"date", editorParams:{
min:"01/01/2020", // the minimum allowed value for the date picker
max:"02/12/2022", // the maximum allowed value for the date picker
format:"dd/MM/yyyy", // the format of the date value stored in the cell
elementAttributes:{
    title:"slide bar to choose option" // custom tooltip
}
```

}}

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
    {title:"Example", field:"example", editor:"date", 
editorParams:function(cell){
    let row = cell.getRow();
    let rowdata = row.getData();
    return {
        min:"01/01/2020",
        max:rowdata.adjacentcell, 
        format:"dd/MM/yyyy", 
        elementAttributes:{
            title:"slide bar to choose option"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck